# Separate asp.net pages into parts

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

Hi can I break the aspx into parts? E.g., one page for head, one page for body, and one for footer, and then combine them? Like that I can hide my JavaScript. Please advise. I can do so in python.

Answer (score 1):

use ASP.NET master pages:

[ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

these are designed exactly for what you need/asked

for example you define content place holders in the master page like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server" >
    <title>Master page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
           <tr>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></td>
               <td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Footer" runat="server" /></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and you populate from another page based on that master page the `Main` and `Footer` contents like this:

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with MasterPages and ContentPages

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a master page?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Also, if you are just trying to keep your javascript separate, you could put all of the javascript into a .js page and include that into you master.